# Using a grammar with a visitor to calculate arithmetic expressions

Tags: antlr, antlr4

We've been given a grammar in class that looks like this:

```
grammar Calculator;

@header {
import java.util.*;
}

@parser::members {
/** "memory" for our calculator; variable/value pairs go here */
Map<String, Double> memory = new HashMap<String, Double>();
}

statlist    :   stat+   ;

stat        :   vgl NL          #printCompare                   
            |   ass NL          #printAssign                        
            |   NL              #blank
            ;

ass         : <assoc=right> VAR ('=') vgl #assign       
            ;               

vgl         :   sum(op=('<'|'>') sum)*  #compare
            ;

sum         :   prod(op=('+'|'-') prod)*    #addSub
            ;

prod        :   pot(op=('*'|'/') pot)*      #mulDiv     
            ;

pot         :<assoc=right> term(op='^' pot)?    #poten
            ;

term        :   '+' term    #add    
            |   '-' term    #subtract
            |   '(' sum ')' #parens
            |   VAR         #var
            |   INT         #int
            ;

/*Rules for the lexer */
MUL :   '*' ; 
DIV :   '/' ;
ADD :   '+' ;
SUB :   '-' ;
BIG :   '>' ;
SML :   '<' ;
POT :   '^' ;
VAR :   [a-zA-Z]+   ;
NL  :   [\n]        ;
INT :   [0-9]+      ;


WS : [ \r\t]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs
```

I am having problems translating constructs like these

```
sum         :   prod(op=('+'|'-') prod)*    #addSub
```

into working code. Currently the corresponding method looks like this:

```
    /** prod(op=('+'|'-') prod)* */
@Override
public Double visitAddSub(CalculatorParser.AddSubContext ctx) {
    double left = visit(ctx.prod(0));
    if(ctx.op == null){
        return left;
    }
    double right = visit(ctx.prod(1));
    return (ctx.op.getType() == CalculatorParser.ADD) ? left+right : left-right;
}
```

Current output would look like this

```
3+3+3
6.0
```

which is obviously false. How do I get my visitor to visit the nodes correctly without touching the grammar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, with the help of Lucas and the usage of `op+=` I manage to fix my problem. It looks pretty complicated but it works.

```
/** prod(op+=('+'|'-') prod)* */
@Override
public Double visitAddSub(CalculatorParser.AddSubContext ctx) {
    Stack<Double> temp = new Stack<Double>();
    switch(ctx.children.size()){
    case 1: return visit(ctx.prod(0));      
    default:
        Double ret = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ctx.op.size(); i++){
            if(ctx.op.get(i).getType()==CalculatorParser.ADD){
                if(temp.isEmpty()) {
                    ret = visit(ctx.prod(i)) + visit(ctx.prod(i+1));
                    temp.push(ret);
                } else {
                    ret = temp.pop() + visit(ctx.prod(i+1));
                    temp.push(ret);
                }
            } else {
                if(temp.isEmpty()) {
                    ret = visit(ctx.prod(i)) - visit(ctx.prod(i+1));
                    temp.push(ret);
                } else {
                    ret = temp.pop() - visit(ctx.prod(i+1));
                    temp.push(ret);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return temp.pop();
}
```

We are using a switch-case to determine how many children this context has. If its more than 3 we have atleast 2 operators. We're then using the individual operator and a stack to determine the result.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the rule:

```
prod(op=('+'|'-') prod)*
```

See that `*`? It means that what's inside the parentheses can come up 0 or more times.

Your visitor code assumes there will either be only one or two child `prod`, but no more. That's why you see `6.0`: the parser put `3+3+3` into the context, but your visitor only processed `3+3` and leaved the final `+3` out.

So just use a `while` loop over all the `op` and `prod` children, and accumulate them into the result.

Comment: That does make alot of sense @Lucas . However am I unsure on how to iterate over the children. op itsself does not posess any and the children from prod(1) for example look like this:


`Input: 3+3+3`
`System.out.println(ctx.children); [[42 34 21 16], +, [44 34 21 16], +, [44 34 21 16]]`
`System.out.println(ctx.prod(0).children);[[50 42 34 21 16]]`
`System.out.println(ctx.prod(1).children);[[50 44 34 21 16]]`

Comment: Looks like you can get all the info you need from the `children` collection.

Comment: for some reason ctx.op is always the last operator. For example, given the input `1+2-3`ctx.op ends up being `-`. I am irritated because 1+2*3 returns 7 with `visit(ctx.prod(1))` returning `6-0`. There has to be something I am missing which makes this easier than iterating over all the children and throwing away the logic given by the derived visitor.

Comment: You asked for a way which doesn't involve changing the grammar. There sure are better ways if you're willing to change it, like using `op+=` instead of `op=`.

Comment: To be fair, the grammar can be touched as long as the logic is not changed. Its supposed to look like [this](http://puu.sh/lHYSl/ad7d0df1a4.png). What actually is the difference between using `op+=` and `op=`?

Comment: `op+=` will add each token into a list.